# SP 2010 - Determine unused mysite so I can delete them

Tags: 2010, my-site

I have many mysite that are created accidentally because user clicked on mysite and sharepoint created a site for them. Is there a way to determine these mysites so i can delete them. (I am not talking about mysite cleanup job which kicks in 60 days after an account is disabled). I see some mysite that was accidentally created when users were using service accounts or admin accounts.

I am not sure if this is the best approach https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262420(v=office.14).aspx Manage unused Web sites

Comment: Can you tell me the version of your SharePoint?

Comment: SharePoint 2010. sorry. i updated the original post. thanks for catching it.

Comment: Can I please get an reply or an expert input on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wrote powershell script to do this. Let me know if anyone wants it.

Answer (score 0):

I did found the workaround to delete the unused mysite in SharePoint 2007.

Please check below link for reference.

[SharePoint Profile Cleanup](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/seanearp/2009/03/04/sharepoint-profile-cleanup/)

I hope it helps you as I don't know if it works for SharePoint 2010 or not.

**UPDATED**

[Inside the SharePoint 2010 My Site Cleanup Timer Job](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2012/06/25/inside-the-sharepoint-2010-my-site-cleanup-timer-job/)

Comment: Did you get it working for you?

Comment: I think this is similar to https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262420(v=office.14).aspx but I will look at it in few. Thanks for the post. Also, like I said in the original post most disable user accounts are automatically taken care off by the mysite cleanup job. so my question is not around this.

Comment: Ok please mark it if it helps you.

Comment: @KevinShort, Please update if you find any resolution for your question

Comment: Hello Kevin, Did you get it working?

Comment: If not than kindly check the steps mentioned in link to manually remove it from my updated answer.